# Error while attempting to send excel attachment using smtplib

Tags: python, email-attachments, smtplib

I'm trying to send an email with an excel file attached using smtplib in python.  I'm getting an error saying:  `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Here is my code:

```
email_message = email.MIMEMultipart.MIMEMultipart('mixed')
excel_attach = email.mime.base.MIMEBase('application','vnd.ms-excel')

# Gives error "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"
excel_attach.set_payload(file(absolute_file_location).read())

email.encoders.encode_base64(excel_attach)
excel_attach.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename={0}'.format(file))
email_message.attach(excel_attach)
```

Why isn't this working?

**EDIT**:  This appears to be the source of error.... `file(absolute_file_location).read()`.  I've determined this by putting it on a different line.

Comment: Have you tried removing `.read()`?

Comment: Oddly enough, I got the same error.  I would've at least expected a different error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with `file(absolute_file_location).read()`

I don't know what the problem was, but getting the contents by doing something like...

```
content = None
with open(file, 'r') as f:
  content = f.read()
  f.close()

excel_attach.set_payload(content)
```

worked as intended.